"something qua something" vs "something simpliciter"
I am wondering if there is a difference between the phrases. I have recently come across a text that uses the phrases "ideology, simpliciter" and "ideology qua ideology" near each other.

While this could just be a pretentious author, I do feel like they have slightly different connotations, but I am unable to express those differences to myself. Both get at the essential nature of something, but "X qua X" seems to me like it is talking about "actual" essential qualities, while "X simpliciter" doesn't feel like it implies a "correct" essence. Is this a commonly accepted difference? I've looked at some dictionaries, and they don't seem to make this distinction.  

If there are any writers here (esp. in law or philosophy) would you just use these terms interchangeably? Am I getting at an actual accepted difference between the terms, or are they too similar to make any definitive statement either way?

You're likely to get better help by asking in [philosophy.se], since this is specifically about how the terms are used in that field.

Or [law.se]. When I try to look up the word "simpliciter" I can only find it in legal dictionaries.

It's hard to find a fundamental difference in how "X qua X" and "X simpliciter" are used. There might be differences in connotation though, with qua suggesting something has multiple aspects and can be considered qua multiple things, while simpliciter means simply. There are many reasons a writer might claim something is simple, including that they don't understand it.

What @Barmar said. The word simpliciter has next to no currency anyway, but it's even less common outside of legal contexts. The only cite in the full OED within the past century is Tony Blair saying If we just accepted this proposal simpliciter, it would give Milosevic exactly what he wanted.  And I'm sure that's Blair (who qualified as a barrister before committing to politics) with his "legal" hat on.

@FumbleFingers Then again, I had to google to find out what "qua" means as well. I've seen it, but very rarely.

@Barmar: I'm used to reading "X qua Y", but that's probably the first time I've ever written it, and I'm sure I've never actually said it (unless I was reading someone else's text out loud). "Simpliciter", though - that's a whole 'nother story!

There is no established difference between the two terms that a reader could be expected to immediately recognize. If they are used in a particular text with a difference in meaning that is a peculiarity of that text, not an established feature of the language.
X qua Y can be rendered in more mundane terminology as X regarded as Y or X considered as Y. X qua X is, consequently, X regarded as X (and not something else), and that is just X, or, if one wants to put it that way, X simpliciter.
